# The item you tried to buy is no longer available [Environment: Sandbox]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to put In App purchase in my application. I had setup a consumable product which was working fine in Sandbox environment. Now i just made a new product which is non-consumable with new price tier, and deleted the old one. Update my code, with the new Product ID. When request is sent, it properly shows the right Product with newly added price tier, But when you tap on Buy button it gives you the error "The item you tried to buy is no longer available [Environment: Sandbox]". Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate new provisional profile and use... I think it will solve the problem.

Comment: i tried this, but no luck :(, generated new profile with new app id, but still the same problem :(

Comment: Check this
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in the above link i posted earlier, and your product is still reported as invalid? You have to wait for 24 hours.. In blog they mentioned that apple may take a day to setup inAppPurchase.

Comment: Well its almost 24 hours since i set up my products, let see what happens? But if i get this error again, might there is some issue in my implementation. But its doesn't appear to be the issue in implementation , because all were working fine few days before, i just added some new non-consumable products and deleted the old consumable one. And this started happening.

Comment: And yes, its done, every thing is working fine again, Its kind a funny, But the solution is "Wait for 24 Hours" :D

I have read some where that this is issue used to occur several time before but momentarily, and solved automatically, but it seems that there is no issue, just a time interval where all the propagation processes are being completed. Either case, my problem is solved.

Anyhow, Thanks a lot Chandan :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to something other than an incorrectly set up payment. Payments I set up and worked last week are also giving the error.